# Assign an additional class to a variable in python (equivalence in R shown)

Tags: python, r, python-3.x, class, oop

In **R**, you can do something like this:

```
x <- 3
cl <- class(x)
class(x) <- c("abc",cl)
```

So variable 'x' will be an integer as well as belong to user-defined class 'abc'.

I want to do a similar thing in **Python**. My variable 'x' should be considered as integer and should also have the attributes of user-defined class named "abc".

Comment: You can do thinks _like_ that, such as subclass `int`. What are your trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: Python classes don't behave like S3 classes. They're more like [R5 classes](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/R5.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Python supports multiple inheritance:

```
class indigestion():
    def burp(self):
        return " ".join("burp" for _ in range(int(self)))


class int_with_indigestion(int, indigestion):
    pass

class float_with_indigestion(float, indigestion):
    pass

n = int_with_indigestion(13)

print(n ** 2)
print(n.burp())

f = float_with_indigestion(5.3)

print(f ** 2)
print(f.burp())
```

**USAGE**

```
> python3 test.py
169
burp burp burp burp burp burp burp burp burp burp burp burp burp
28.09
burp burp burp burp burp
>
```